# Stuck script when saving stringified object using big json library

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

In my app I have a big object (>600Mb) and I'd like to stringify it and save it in a json file - because of it's size I'd like to use `big-json` library and `json.createStringifyStream` method which returns a stringified object stream. My script looks like this:

```
import json from 'big-json'


const fetchAt = new Date();
const myData = // big object >600MB
const myDataFileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('./myfile.json');
json.createStringifyStream({body: myData})
    .pipe(myDataFileWriteStream)
    .on('finish', function () {
        const writeAt = new Date();
        console.log(`Data written in ${(writeAt - fetchAt) / 1000} seconds.`); // this line is never printed out
     });
```

When I run it I can see that it's saving the data for some time - After that it freezes and stops doing anything - but the script doesn't finish:

1. It doesn't print the log hooked on the `finish` event
2. The file is much smaller than I anticipate
3. The script doesn't exit

I run it for like 30 minutes and no sign of finishing - it uses 0 CPU. Do you spot any problem ? What might be the cause ?

Edit:
I have a working example - please clone https://github.com/solveretur/big-json-test and run `npm start` . After ~15 minutes it should freeze and won't finish - I use node@14

Comment: No error in console?

Comment: no error, no nothing - it looks like it's still being executed but when I check the process it uses 0CPU / the output file size doesn't increase

Comment: Can you create a complete fiddle?

Comment: Have you tried running your code on a small js object?

Comment: > Can you create a complete fiddle? – 
I'll try - you can set `    const myData = [];
    for(var i =0; i < 10000000; ++i){
        myData.push({'id': i, 'name': 'SomeName'})
    }` and it should happen

Comment: > Have you tried running your code on a small js object?  - yes I did and it's working

Comment: @SimoneRossaini here's an example https://github.com/solveretur/big-json-test  - please clone and do npm start

Comment: @ClydeBarrow it completed for me: "Synthesis: data written in 615.546 seconds"

Comment: @robertklep - and you haven't change anything ? I use `npm 6.14.17` / `node v14.20.1` and use macOS

Comment: @ClydeBarrow I only fixed the call to `resolve()` (moved it into the `finish` handler), but I realize now that I used Node.js v17.5.0 (on macOS), not v14.

Comment: ok I solved it - turns out it needed `--max-old-space-size=4096` and took 35 minutes but it finally finished - thanks for help !